# Cythonized Python.Net code cannot find system assemblies

Tags: python, cython, clr, python.net

When I compile with Cython the Python code which uses Python.NET to access .NET assemblies, it can't find those assemblies:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'System'
```

Without compilation it works ok.

For demo code, I used https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/demo/helloform.py

My `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        'helloform',
        sources = ['helloform.py'],
        language = 'c++'
      )
]

setup(
  name = 'helloform',
  ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules),
)
```

Then I build it with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.

I wanted to load compiled module from Python prompt with `import helloform` but it failed with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "helloform.py", line 8, in init helloform
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'System'
```

Comment: Linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129939/importing-clr-python-net-code-in-python-or-cython-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is untested - I don't think I can easily set up an environment to test so it's a bit of a guess. If it doesn't work I'll remove it.

This probably is a bug, and if you want it fixed in the longer term you [should report it](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues). Cython does try to be compatible with Python wherever possible.... A quick investigate suggests that [Python.NET overrides the built-in `__import__` function](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/e5d299ea67c46bfd729e85328801b19b3dfe44fb/src/runtime/importhook.cs#L43). Cython [looks to lookup and use this function in Python 2, but not in Python 3](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/c97860d33ad3b894499a66eefb7e49d2cb11435e/Cython/Utility/ImportExport.c#L167). This is [no longer the preferred way of customizing import behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) (but is still supported). I'd guess it would work in Cython + Python 2?

As a workaround you should probably just run the import statements in Python. There's two obvious ways to do it:

1. Write a small separate module just containing the import statements, then in Cython import from that module:

   ```
   from import_module import WinForms, Size, Point
   ```
2. Run the import statements in `exec`; extract the values out of the global dict you pass it:

   ```
   import_dict = {}
   exec("""import clr
   # etc...
   """, import_dict) # pass a dict in as `globals`
   WinForms = import_dict['WinForms']
   # etc.
   ```

Comment: Yes I already tested with separate module, seems to work. I raised a ticket to pythonnet's github page, thanks

Comment: I was suggesting raising it as a Cython bug instead, since Cython does aim to be compatible with Python, and this isn't quite. It probably won't be fixed promptly but it's always possible...

Comment: Done as well, sadly there is no easy way to cross-post on Github ;)

Comment: @crayxt Have you solved this in the meantime? Would you have the link to your Github issue? Here I also created one: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/1890. Thanks in advance if you have an idea!